# What is the optimal way to get value from widget?

Tags: flutter

I want to create Filters widget like this:

```
Filters<int>(
  items: [
    FilterItem(label: 'All', value: 1),
    FilterItem(label: 'Today', value: 2),
    FilterItem(label: 'Unwatched', value: 3),
),
```

Which will provide selected value higher to widget tree

I see multiple ways to do this. But I want to know downsides of each.

1. Pass mutable selected value (like `List<T>` with one element, which will represent active value)
2. Pass `Key` to the `Filters<T>` to get public `T` selected value
3. Callback `void Function(T)` which will trigger when new filter is selected
4. Manage it to work with `ValueNotifier<T>`

Like, in 1st example value will stay in `WidgetTree` instead of `ElementTree`, but is it necessarily a bad thing?

Comment: if you see most of built in widget in flutter, they use method 3. ex. `void Function onSelected(T value)` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple

1. Ok. If you have no need to update UI (you don't know if value had been updated and you need to call setState)
2. Ok. Same as 1st approach, maybe little better because now widget has a key
3. Good. If you have just one simple action with one widget to update UI - use callback for it
4. Good. If you have multiple listeners or values to listen (also, better to use some package like `provider` for this)